# Sequences of Integers such that no one divides the product of two others.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm working on of a [problem](http://books.google.com/books?id=SbZKSZ-1qrwC&pg=PA139) of Bollobas' Modern Graph Theory, but I can't seem to get the last part of the problem:

Let $1<a_1<a_2< \cdots a_k \leq x$ be natural numbers. Suppose no $a_i$ divides the product of any two others. Prove that $k \leq \pi(x)+x^{2/3}$, where $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime counting function. [Hint: Put $X = \{1, \dots,\lfloor x^{2/3} \rfloor\}$ and $V_2 = \{ x: x^{2/3}\leq b \leq x, \mbox{ b is prime}\}$. Show first that $a_i=b_ic_i$, where $b_i,c_i \in V_1 
\cup V_2$. Consider the graph on $V_1$ and $V_2$, $G$, with edges $b_ic_i$]

It is clear to me that any such integer can be written in the form above. It is also clear that $G$ contains no path of length $3$. So, $G$ must be a collection of stars, or single edges with loops on one of the endpoints. However, I am not able to get the bound $\pi(x)+x^{2/3}$ on the number of edges.

I observe that the graph above has at most as many edges as vertices, but $G$ has $\pi(x)-\pi(x^{2/3})+\lfloor x^{2/3} \rfloor$ vertices. How do I count the edges in order to get the proper bound?

Comment: But $\pi(x) -\pi(x^{2/3})+\lfloor x^{2/3}\rfloor < \pi(x) + x^{2/3}$.

Comment: Boy, I feel silly. Thank you anyways.

Also, I'll be sure to use the graph-theory tag in future.